# How do you apply DCT steganography on an RGB image?

Tags: python, opencv, steganography

I am working on a project to make a DCT based steganography program in Python and I found a working model in Github. The program, however, can only encode on one of the RGB channels. Resulting in a discolored image. The image is split into RGB bands using OpenCV and DCT and quantization is done only on the blue channel and then it is combined with the rest of the channels. Is there a way to make it work on all channels or avoid discoloration.

I have referred the dct compression on RGB images to find a solution and found out that dct and quantization must be done for all 3 bands separately and then compression is done. Should I do the same here also? As in encode the same message three times in all bands to avoid discoloration?

**Encoding Algorithm**

```
def encode_image(self,img,secret_msg):

        secret=secret_msg
        self.message = str(len(secret))+'*'+secret
        print(self.message)
        self.bitMess = self.toBits()
        print(self.bitMess)
        row,col = img.shape[:2]
        self.oriRow, self.oriCol = row, col  
        if((col/8)*(row/8)<len(secret)):
            print("Error: Message too large to encode in image")
            return False
        #make divisible by 8x8
        if row%8 != 0 or col%8 != 0:
            img = self.addPadd(img, row, col)

        row,col = img.shape[:2]
        ##col, row = img.size
        #split image into RGB channels
        bImg,gImg,rImg = cv2.split(img)



 def enc(bImg):
        #message to be hid in blue channel so converted to type float32 for dct function
        bImg = np.float32(bImg)
        #break into 8x8 blocks
        imgBlocks = [np.round(bImg[j:j+8, i:i+8]-128) for (j,i) in itertools.product(range(0,row,8),
                                                                    range(0,col,8))]
        #Blocks are run through DCT function
        dctBlocks = [np.round(cv2.dct(img_Block)) for img_Block in imgBlocks]

        #blocks then run through quantization table
        quantizedDCT = [np.round(dct_Block/quant) for dct_Block in dctBlocks]
        #set LSB in DC value corresponding bit of message
        messIndex = 0
        letterIndex = 0
        for quantizedBlock in quantizedDCT:
            #find LSB in DC coeff and replace with message bit
            DC = quantizedBlock[0][0]
            DC = np.uint8(DC)
            DC = np.unpackbits(DC)

            DC[7] = self.bitMess[messIndex][letterIndex]


            DC = np.packbits(DC)
            DC = np.float32(DC)
            DC= DC-255
            quantizedBlock[0][0] = DC
            letterIndex = letterIndex+1
            if letterIndex == 8:
                letterIndex = 0
                messIndex = messIndex + 1
                if messIndex == len(self.message):
                    break
        #blocks run inversely through quantization table
        sImgBlocks = [quantizedBlock *quant+128 for quantizedBlock in quantizedDCT]
        #blocks run through inverse DCT
        sImgDCT = [cv2.idct(B)+128 for B in sImgBlocks]
        #puts the new image back together
        sImg=[]
        for chunkRowBlocks in self.chunks(sImgDCT, col/8):
            for rowBlockNum in range(8):
                for block in chunkRowBlocks:
                    sImg.extend(block[rowBlockNum])
        sImg = np.array(sImg).reshape(row, col)
        #converted from type float32
        sImg = np.uint8(sImg)
        return sImg
    bImg=enc(bImg)
    #show(sImg)
    sImg = cv2.merge((bImg,gImg,rImg))
    return sImg
```

**Decoding Algorithm**

```
def decode_image(self,img):
        row,col = img.shape[:2]
        messSize = None
        messageBits = []
        buff = 0
        #split image into RGB channels
        bImg,gImg,rImg = cv2.split(img)
         #message hid in blue channel so converted to type float32 for dct function
        bImg = np.float32(bImg)
        #break into 8x8 blocks
        imgBlocks = [bImg[j:j+8, i:i+8]-128 for (j,i) in itertools.product(range(0,row,8),
                                                                       range(0,col,8))]    
        #blocks run through quantization table
        dctBlocks = [cv2.dct(img_Block) for img_Block in imgBlocks]
        #quantizedDCT = [dct_Block/ (quant) for dct_Block in dctBlocks]
        quantizedDCT = [dct_Block/quant for dct_Block in dctBlocks]
        i=0
        #message extracted from LSB of DC coeff
        for quantizedBlock in quantizedDCT:
            DC = quantizedBlock[0][0]
            DC = np.uint8(DC)
            DC = np.unpackbits(DC)
            if DC[7] == 1:
                buff+=(0 & 1) << (7-i)
            elif DC[7] == 0:
                buff+=(1&1) << (7-i)
            i=1+i
            if i == 8:
                messageBits.append(chr(buff))
                buff = 0
                i =0
                if messageBits[-1] == '*' and messSize is None:
                    try:
                        messSize = int(''.join(messageBits[:-1]))
                    except:
                        pass
            if len(messageBits) - len(str(messSize)) - 1 == messSize:
                return ''.join(messageBits)[len(str(messSize))+1:]
        #blocks run inversely through quantization table
        sImgBlocks = [quantizedBlock *quant+128 for quantizedBlock in quantizedDCT]
        #blocks run through inverse DCT
        #sImgBlocks = [cv2.idct(B)+128 for B in quantizedDCT]
        #puts the new image back together
        sImg=[]
        for chunkRowBlocks in self.chunks(sImgBlocks, col/8):
            for rowBlockNum in range(8):
                for block in chunkRowBlocks:
                    sImg.extend(block[rowBlockNum])
        sImg = np.array(sImg).reshape(row, col)
        #converted from type float32
        sImg = np.uint8(sImg)
        sImg = cv2.merge((sImg,gImg,rImg))
        ##sImg.save(img)
        #dct_decoded_image_file = "dct_" + original_image_file
        #cv2.imwrite(dct_decoded_image_file,sImg)
        return ''

    """Helper function to 'stitch' new image back together"""
    def chunks(self, l, n):
        m = int(n)
        for i in range(0, len(l), m):
            yield l[i:i + m]
    def addPadd(self,img, row, col):
        img = cv2.resize(img,(col+(8-col%8),row+(8-row%8)))    
        return img
    def toBits(self):
        bits = []
        for char in self.message:
            binval = bin(ord(char))[2:].rjust(8,'0')
            bits.append(binval)
        self.numBits = bin(len(bits))[2:].rjust(8,'0')
        return bits
```

Comment: IMHO this is not really a programming question and would probably get a better answer on https://dsp.StackExchange.com

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think you meant https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The link you provided is not working. Can you please provide the correct link?

Comment: Since you have posted on DSP.SE, I would delete this question. Cross-posting is considered a violation of etiquette, as it is wasteful to answer a question that has already been answered in another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: You could convert to HSV and encode the message in the V channel, then combine that with the original H and S channels. That would avoid any color change.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried converting to HSV and ran it through the program but the picture looks worse now. It looks like a negative version. I converted to HSV and encoded in the v channel. Then I merged it and converted it back to RGB. I used the same encoding algorithm I used for RGB. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like you encoded the hue channel, not the value channel.        `img= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` `bImg,gImg,rImg = cv2.split(img)` `def enc(bImg):` The value image is rImg not bImg. You only want to encode the value channel and not the hue or saturation channels.

Comment: @fmw42 `def enc(bImg):` is a variable which I gave while defining the def if you can traverse to the end of that def you can see that I called it using rImg  `rImg=enc(rImg)`

Comment: OK. Then I am not sure what is wrong. Perhaps you need to clip your result when converting back to uint8.

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The GUI stuff is irrelevant. Just feed the parameters straight to your functions. The code does too much. Converts to a different colour space, splits into blocks and performs DCT/IDCT. Convert to HSV and directly back to RGB. If that works fine, remove it. Similar with the blocks. Once you've trimmed down the excess, you should provide us with an input (even if it's an array of 8x8 numbers) so we can reproduce where the error.

Comment: @Reti43 I have separated the encoding and decoding function and have posted it above. You may use the encoding algorithm only to see the output image.for an input I suggest using any png image. You will see the problem in the output. I also noticed the quantized block we get before embedding mostly has all zero values except the first value (0,0). I hope this was of some use.